# Finding every X,Y position of a horizontally moving element

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, position

I'm having quite a bit of trouble with this. Here's what I have so far:

```
var findPos = function(obj){
    var curLeft = 0;
    var curTop = 0;
    var arr = [];

    curLeft += obj.offsetLeft;
    curTop += obj.offsetTop;
    arr[arr.length] = {x: curLeft, y: curTop}; 
    return arr;
}
```

This only returns the starting position of the element passed into the function. But as the object move, I want it to store every position (x, y) in the array that is returned. Any suggestion as to how this can be done? I have tried recursion but that didn't really work out.

The element is moving using CSS `@keyframes` if that is relevant.

Comment: IF you declare arr as a local variable in findPos, then it will be reset to an empty array every time you call findPos.  Declare arr outside of this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mbeckish has the right idea, and since the array would be global, you don't necessarily need to return it - it will be updated by the function.  Also, it doesn't seem necessary to "accumulate" the x,y positions using the `curLeft`/`curTop` variables.  The offset should be sufficient.  You need something like this:

```
var arr = [];

var findPos = function(obj){
    arr[arr.length] = {x:obj.offsetLeft, y:obj.offsetTop}; 
}
```

To track the animation over time you could use the setInterval() or setTimeout() function, so something like this:

```
var intRef = window.setInterval(function(){ findPos(obj) }, 100);
```

The above will fire off every 100 milliseconds and populate your array.  This will go on indefinitely, however, until you stop it, so you need some kind of trigger or end-time.  To turn off the coordinate tracking, use:

```
window.clearInterval(intRef);
```

Comment: Thank you. I realize some of my code is redundant, But I'm still struggling with getting every position as the object move. Any tips there? :)

Comment: @Nilzone- - the best you could probably do is use the `setInterval()` function to call your `findPos()` function every so often.  If you go that route, however, you might as well animate the element manually and keep track of the x,y positions and you update them.

Comment: I'll try that - thanks! But It kinda bugs me the fact that I cant get it to work with recursion

Comment: @Nilzone- - I'm not sure where recursion (a function calling itself) would be necessary for something like this.  That technique is typically used to solve a divide-and-conquer problem...

Comment: Fair enough - anyway, setInterval really helped - Thank you! :)